# Login, Usuarios

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Estoy realizando un portal web para un colegio. El mismo desea que sus alumnos puedan verificar sus calificaciones en dicha pagina que está desarrollada en *HTML5*, *PHP* y *MYSQL*.

Yo realicé una Base de Datos con USUARIO y CONTRASEÑA para que los alumnos puedan ingresar al área de verificación de notas, pero las mismas la estoy montando página por página y no lo quiero así. Quisiera que luego de registrarse lo redireccione, o le de acceso a sus datos en una sola plantilla, y que le muestra sus calificaciones al ser exportadas desde la tabla de *MYSQL*.

Comment: Necesitarías almacenar la id del usuario logueado en una sesión de PHP o similar al suceder el logueo positivo. Luego te bastaría con hacer una query para obtener las notas del usuario que coincida con ese id. Como este parámetro variaría dependiendo de quien loguee te sirve para servir información personalizada a cada uno de los alumnos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, pero al decir que realice un query tendrías un ejemplo de ello para estar más claro?

Comment: A que tendrías que lanzar una cosulta a tu **DB** similar a: `"select * from notas where id_alumno = $_SESSION['id_alumno']"` para obtener todas las notas del alumno que loguea a la sesión y así poder usar esta información para mostrar los datos de dicho alumno. Deberías mirar como funcionan las sesiones en PHP. https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Muéstranos qué has intentado. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ya trabajaré en ella

Comment: Bienvenido Alberto, recuerda lo comentado por DjCrazy e intenta que las preguntas sean lo más claras posibles :)
Mi aporte, es que recuerdes que las contraseñas han de ser almacenadas encriptadas, hay distintos algoritmos de encriptación, pero lo básico, es que no puedes acceder tu u otra persona a la password directamente.
Si necesitas ayuda con ello, google te brindará muchísima ayuda y si encuentras un ejemplo que no sabes cómo implementar o te da algún fallo, crea una pregunta y gustosamente te ayudaremos :)
Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo Rubén Espada por su aporte, me documentaré lo más que pueda para lograr mi objetivo que tengo poco tiempo